# Aumentar tamaño asignado a los inodes

Tags: servidor

Tengo un servidor que me esta dando problemas. Ejecutando el comando `df-ih` obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la captura tengo un tamaño de 1.3M para los inodes. Al menos eso entiendo. Acabo descubrir ese concepto. No soy experto en servidores ni linux y en este caso es un servidor que no he montado yo. Simplemente le mantengo como buenamente puedo.

Buscando he encontrado [maneras de listar](https://tecnowarp.blogspot.com/2017/06/limpiar-inodos-linux-al-100.html) donde se almacenan pero yo lo que quisiera seria poder ampliar ese tamaño ya que no quiero borrar nada del servidor. ¿Habría alguna posibilidad de aumentar ese tamaño?

Muchas gracias de antemano espero me haya explicado bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como continuación de la respuesta de @Bryro. Tienes que eliminar los archivos creados en demasiada cantidad.

Vamos a suponer que tu estructura de archivos es esta:

```
<directorio>
├── dir1
│   ├── sub1
│   │   ├── bad_dir
│   │   └── sub2
│   └── sub2
│       ├── sub1
│       └── sub2
├── dir2
│   ├── sub1
│   │   ├── sub1
│   │   └── sub2
│   └── sub2
│       ├── sub1
│       └── sub2
└── dir3
    ├── sub1
    │   ├── sub1
    │   └── sub2
    └── sub2
        ├── sub1
        └── sub2
```

Y dentro de "bad_dir" tenemos muchos archivos pero no lo sabemos de antemano.

Mi propuesta es correr este comando múltiples veces:

```
$ find <directorio> -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs -I % bash -c "echo -n %: ; find % | wc -l" 2> /dev/null
```

La primera vez tenemos esto (es un ejemplo):

```
./dir1:124
./dir2:25
./dir3:25
```

Entonces ejecutamos de nuevo ese comando sobre `./dir1`:

```
$ find ./dir1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs -I % bash -c "echo -n %: ; find % | wc -l" 2> /dev/null
#         |____ Cambiamos de directorio.
./dir1/sub1:111
./dir1/sub2:12
```

Y repetimos:

```
$ find ./dir1/sub1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs -I % bash -c "echo -n %: ; find % | wc -l" 2> /dev/null
./dir1/sub1/bad_dir:100
./dir1/sub1/sub2:10
```

Y así te puedes dar cuenta de qué directorio posee mas archivos para después borrarlos.

Yo revisaría en `/home`, `/tmp`, `/var`, para evitar soltar el golpe sobre la raíz `/`.

Por ejemplo, en mi computadora personal corrí lo siguiente:

```
$ find / -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
   | xargs -I % bash -c "echo -n %: ; find % | wc -l" 2> /dev/null \
   | sort -t ":" -k 2 -nr \
   | head -n 4
```

Donde indico en mi *pipeline* que me arroje las 4 carpetas con mas archivos, ordenadas de mayor a menor. Tu puedes obtener lo que quieras variando el valor de `head -n <valor>`

Y después de unos minutos obtuve esto:

```
/usr:74738
/home:39084
/var:5158
/tmp:3213
```

algo semejante de puede guiar.

Comment: GRACIASSS!!!!. He dado con ellos gracias a esto me has pasado. Dentro de /usr había un directorio donde se guardaban los ticket de aviso que creaba el servidor. Se habían ido guardando allí desde 2018 que por lo visto se monto el servidor. Cada uno ocupaba un inode y estaban saturando todo. Muchas gracias. Saludos

Comment: Super, ¡Que bien! Me alegra mucho haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Que es [inodo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inodo)

Un disco con 0 inodos disponibles probablemente esté lleno de archivos muy pequeños, en algún lugar de un directorio específico (aplicaciones, archivos tmp, archivos pid, archivos de sesión, ...). Cada archivo usa ( al menos ) 1 inodo. Muchos millones de archivos usarían muchos millones de inodes.

Si los inodos de sus discos están llenos, ¿cómo lo aumenta? La respuesta difícil es que probablemente no puedas.

La cantidad de inodos disponibles en un sistema se decide tras la creación de la partición. Por ejemplo, una partición predeterminada de EXT3 / EXT4 tiene una relación de bytes por inodo de un inodo cada 16384 bytes (16 Kb) .